# Has any Latter-day Saint published a very detailed description of how the Holy Spirit confirmed to them the truth of the BofM, as per Moroni 10:3-7?

Tags: lds, resource-request, book-of-mormon, supernatural, testimony

[Moroni 10:3-7](https://abn.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/bofm/moro/10?lang=eng):

> 3 Behold, I would exhort you that when ye shall read these things, if it be wisdom in God that ye should
> read them, that ye would remember how merciful the Lord hath been
> unto the children of men, from the creation of Adam even down until
> the time that ye shall receive these things, and ponder it in your
> hearts.
>
> 4 And when ye shall receive these things, **I would exhort you that ye**
> **would ask God, the Eternal Father, in the name of Christ, if these**
> **things are not true; and if ye shall ask with a sincere heart, with**
> **real intent, having faith in Christ, he will manifest the truth of it**
> **unto you, by the power of the Holy Ghost**.
>
> 5 **And by the power of the Holy Ghost ye may know the truth of all**
> **things**.
>
> 6 And whatsoever thing is good is just and true; wherefore, nothing
> that is good denieth the Christ, but acknowledgeth that he is.
>
> 7 **And ye may know that he is, by the power of the Holy Ghost**;
> wherefore I would exhort you that ye deny not the power of God; for he
> worketh by power, according to the faith of the children of men, the
> same today and tomorrow, and forever.

Has any Latter-day Saint published **a very detailed description** of the day when they undertook Moroni 10:3-7's challenge and, as a result, had an extraordinary experience from the Holy Spirit that confirmed to them the authenticity of the Book of Mormon?

*Note: when I say published, I mean published in any format (book, magazine, website/blog, YouTube video, podcast, etc). By very detailed, I mean ideally a decent amount of paragraphs just to describe the experience itself. And by extraordinary, I mean any kind of experience that cannot be easily explained away as a mere psychological phenomenon.*

Comment: @depperm Any of those formats would be fine. Even a YouTube video would be ok.

Comment: @depperm - by very detailed, I mean ideally a decent amount of paragraphs just to describe the experience itself. And by extraordinary, I mean any kind of experience that cannot be easily explained away as a mere psychological phenomenon.

Comment: see this [answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/83924/22319) bottom

Comment: @depperm - actually that answer inspired me to ask this question :-). The problem with that that answer though is that the experience itself is not described with many details, the description is essentially *"I immediately received a powerful, strong witness that he had indeed sent it to the Earth for that very purpose. Nothing can take that experience from me"*. What is meant by "powerful, strong witness"?

Comment: "cannot be easily explained away as a mere psychological phenomenon" There is no shortage of antichrists, apostates and psychiatrists who are trying their darnedest to do exactly that.  To the shallow-minded, absolutely anything they don't like can be "explained away" as a mere psychological phenomenon, including reality itself. But I suppose we are trying to be inclusive of those who are more reasonable, as well as making ourselves open to descriptions of faith. As well might Peter try to describe what it was like to be on the Mount of Transfiguration with the Lord, as to put this to words.

Comment: @pygosceles - to illustrate the point, an example of a phenomenon that cannot be easily explained away is the [Kundalini awakening](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/26179/explanation-for-the-spinal-energy-and-other-kundalini-awakening-symptoms).

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator In your mind, is the primary reason why it cannot easily be explained away due to the quantity of data (reports/testimonies/records of experiences), the apparent richness and complexity of the experiences, the lack of physical and physiological theories to describe a deterministic law undergirding these events, something else, or a combination of the above?

Comment: @pygosceles - I think a combination of the above, and the fact that the best "explanations" out there assume a Hinduist worldview with "chakras" and bodily "energies", which is obviously incompatible with a naturalist worldview (see the only answer to the question, which I received via email from a researcher on the kundalini awakening phenomenon).

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator I am glad you seem to take a more rational approach to this subject than most. There are fragments of truth scattered among the various religions and nations of the earth; the greatest task would be to find the threads that unify the families of the world into a shared understanding of truth. It will not be arrived at without honesty and wholesome curiosity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many times. Although it is possible that the details they provide are not the details this question specifically seeks.

One of my favorites is the account of Vincenzo di Francesca, who first read the Book of Mormon in 1910. His experience is recorded [here](https://abn.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/ensign/1988/01/i-will-not-burn-the-book?lang=eng), and was later made into a video [here](https://youtu.be/3hsF4fRzL44).

His experience was unusual in that he found the book on an ash heap and the introductory pages were missing. He came to a testimony of the truthfulness of the messages before (years later) finding out what the book was named or by whom it was published.

Another well-known account is that of Parley P. Pratt (1807-1857). He recorded his experience in gaining a testimony of the Book of Mormon in his [autobiography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001VNCI6E), and for those looking for a free source, a low-cost film telling the (highlights of) his story is available on YouTube [here](https://youtu.be/ZQFbsi2-Sjc).

I provide a brief discussion of my own experiences on my channel [here](https://youtu.be/E1jiTecD9K0); though I share fewer details than I expect the OP is looking for.

The difficulty in putting into words a profound experience is explored by Boyd K. Packer (who was an apostle of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints) [here](https://abn.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/liahona/1988/12/the-candle-of-the-lord?lang=eng).

Comment: here are some more, don't think its worth its own answer: https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/ensign/2016/10/young-adults/converted-for-life?lang=eng, https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/new-era/1973/06/stories-from-the-general-authorities-my-conversion?lang=eng, https://africawest.churchofjesuschrist.org/conversion-story:-michael-ansah-sackey, https://youtu.be/2mNOXEmxhE8